# How to fix 'The DocumentName value is not specified.' Even if DocumentName property is already supplied

Tags: kentico

I'm using the DancingGoatMVC sample of Kentico.

Now I'm testing if I can add an Article page using the api.

Basically I added new method to the article controller and views.

As you can see I'm already populating the DocumentName but the error is still occurring, any ideas to solve this error and what I might be missing that is causing this issue?

Thanks

Controllers:

```
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(ArticleViewModel articleViewModel)
    {
        // Creates a new instance of the Tree provider
        TreeProvider tree = new         TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);

        // Gets the current site's root "/" page, which will serve as the         parent page
        TreeNode parentPage = tree.SelectNodes()
            .Path("/Articles")
            .OnCurrentSite()
            .Culture("en-us")
            .FirstObject;

        if (parentPage.DocumentName != null)
        {
            TreeNode newPage = TreeNode.New(SystemDocumentTypes.Root, 
        tree);

            // Sets the properties of the new page
            newPage.DocumentName = "Articles";
            newPage.DocumentCulture = "en-us";
            newPage.SetValue("Title", "test");
            newPage.SetValue("Summary", "test");
            newPage.SetValue("Text", "test");

            newPage.SetValue("DocumentName", "Articles");
            // Inserts the new page as a child of the parent page
            newPage.Insert(parentPage,true);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Error:

Server Error in '/Kentico12_DancingGoatMvc' Application.
The DocumentName value is not specified.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: The DocumentName value is not specified.

Source Error:

Line 90:                 newPage.SetValue("DocumentName", "Articles");
Line 91:                 // Inserts the new page as a child of the parent page
Line 92:                 newPage.Insert(parentPage,true);
Line 93:             }
Line 94:

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Kentico12\DancingGoatMvc\Controllers\ArticlesController.cs    Line: 92

Stack Trace:

[Exception: The DocumentName value is not specified.]
   CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode.InsertNode(TreeNode parent) in D:\CMS\MAIN\CMSSolution\DocumentEngine\Documents\TreeNode.cs:4008
   CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode.Insert(TreeNode parent, Boolean useDocumentHelper) in D:\CMS\MAIN\CMSSolution\DocumentEngine\Documents\TreeNode.cs:3959
   CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentHelper.InsertDocument(TreeNode node, TreeNode parentNode, TreeProvider tree, Boolean allowCheckOut) in D:\CMS\MAIN\CMSSolution\DocumentEngine\DocumentHelper.cs:457
   CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode.Insert(TreeNode parent, Boolean useDocumentHelper) in D:\CMS\MAIN\CMSSolution\DocumentEngine\Documents\TreeNode.cs:3946
   DancingGoat.Controllers.ArticlesController.Add(ArticleViewModel articleViewModel) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Kentico12\DancingGoatMvc\Controllers\ArticlesController.cs:92
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +139
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +229
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +77
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +387
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +387
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +387
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +387
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +602
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128

Answer (score 0):

This line here appears to be the problem:

`newPage.SetValue("DocumentName", "Articles")`

Why are you assigning it like this when you're already assigning it above?

Secondly, is your `DocumentName` property based on another required property of the page type like `Title`?  You can see this under the Fields definition of the page type.  The dropdown will be directly under the Field names box.